# Why doesn't typeof work but isNaN works ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend

Why doesn't this block work?  I Used isNaN() and that works but not this, why? Javascript is behaving weirdly.

```
 if( (typeof parseInt(returnedArr[count]) == 'number')
                {
                    totalWorth= parseInt(totalWorth)+ parseInt(returnedArr[count]); 
                    //document.write(returnedArr[count]);

                }
```

Code:

```
function addWorth()
{ 


    var table1= document.getElementById("tableNetWorths");

    var rowCount1= table1.rows.length;

    //var row1= table1.insertRow(rowCount1);


    var arr= [];


   for(var count = 0; count < rowCount1; count++)
   {    
        arr.push(table1.rows[count].cells[1].innerHTML);          
   }


   arr.shift();
   return arr;

} 

function showWorthSum()
{
    var returnedArr= addWorth();

    //returnedArr.push(addWorth());

     totalWorth= 0;

    var arrCount= returnedArr.length;

    for(var count = 0; count < arrCount; count++)
    {    


            if( (typeof parseInt(returnedArr[count]) == 'number')
            {
                totalWorth= parseInt(totalWorth)+ parseInt(returnedArr[count]); 
                //document.write(returnedArr[count]);

            }






    }

    return parseInt(totalWorth);
}
```

If I use isNaN then that works but not this, why? My array looks like this:

{"100", "200", "asdasdadsa", "1"}

Comment: `parseInt` always returns a `Number`.

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking, but that if statement should pass for every element in your array because `typeof NaN` is `"number"`

Answer (score 1):

Because `typeof NaN` is `"number"`:

```js
console.log(typeof NaN);
```

`NaN` is a special value* of the number type, not its own type.

You haven't shown your code that uses `isNaN`, but note that if you pass a string into `isNaN`, it will be implicitly converted to number before being tested to see if the result of doing that is `NaN` (as though you had called `Number(x)` on it, or applied unary `+` or any of the non-addition math ops [`-`, `*`, `/`, etc.]).

Separately:

- Beware that `parseInt` will happily parse a string that only *starts* with a number, ignoring the part after it that isn't numeric. For instance, `parseInt("123abc")` is `123`.
- Beware that when used without its second argument, `parseInt` will infer the number base (radix) from the string, so `parseInt("0x10")` is `16`.

When dealing with user input, handling both of those situations intentionally is usually best:

```
function parseIntStrict(str) {
    str = str.trim();
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(str)) {
        return NaN;
    }
    return parseInt(str, 10);
}
```

(Note that doesn't attempt to support scientific notation input; users don't usually input it.)

And for floating point:

```
function parseFloatStrict(str) {
    str = str.trim();
    if (!str) {
        return NaN;
    }
    return +str;
}
```

(That *does* support scientific notation, but only as a byproduct of only checking for blank strings before handing off to built-in numeric conversion.)

Applying that to your code:

```
// I assume totalWorth is already a number
var entry = parseIntStrict(returnedArr[count]);
if (!isNaN(entry)) {
    totalWorth = totalWorth + entry;
}
```

---

* Technically, per the IEEE-754 standard JavaScript uses, `NaN` is any of a range of values that all mean "not a number."

Answer (score -2):

This is because the values in the array that you consider to be numbers are actually strings. For example, 100 is a number, but '100' is a string. typeof 123 will return 'number', but typeof '123' will return 'string'. 
This means that all the values in your array are of type string and your code will not enter the if statement, if you use that approach. 
However, since isNaN checks if an element in not a number, your code will work with that.